# 'perl' is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: perl, strawberry-perl

I have found old posts regarding this issue, but I haven't found a successful answer,that's why I decided to post again.
I have installed Strawberry-perl.
I have all the folders and subfolders that it's supposed to have:

```
C:\Strawberry
C:\Strawberry\c
C:\Strawberry\cpan
C:\Strawberry\licenses
C:\Strawberry\perl
C:\Strawberry\win32
```

`C:\Strawberry\perl\bin` is included in the path environment variable (pointing the folder where I have the perl.exe file

However, I still get the message
'perl' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Any suggestion?

Thanks

Comment: Have you restarted your terminal(command prompt) since you made the environment variable change?

Comment: Please open an command prompt and provide the output of `echo %PATH%` and of `perl -E"say ok"`

Comment: Are you *sure* it's in the PATH variable?  Do `echo %PATH%` and make sure it's in the list.  You may need to restart your command prompt for it to take hold.

Comment: Is this Windows 32-bit or 64-bit?